# Java outputStream "\n" not working as expected on cmd

Tags: java, cmd, printing, serversocket, outputstream

I am playing around with serverSocket, i found that when connecting in cmd and trying to display output on next line using "\n" the next string does not start from the beginning of the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    outputStream.write(("Time is " + new Date() + "\n").getBytes());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

CMD output:

[image: cmd]

Comment: Try System.lineSeparator() instead of '\n'

Comment: lineSeparator worked like a charm, also i found that adding \r before \n also works, thanks for the help

Comment: outputStream.write(("Time is " +new Date() + System.lineSeparator() ).getBytes());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Info***

Unlike other operating systems with `"\n"` as line break, Windows has `"\r\n"`.
(Also mind that the command line is buffered.)

- `"\r"` = CR = Carriage Return = go to the beginning of the line
- `"\n"` = LF = Line Feed = go to next line

This is the classical type writer control "API."

(Carriage is a small carriage on a rail with a (ofter V-form) opening for printing a letter. A handle to the right first moves the carriage to the left, and further pressing moves the roll up 2 half-lines.)

I would not have expected to see this demonstrated as still to exist in Windows/CMD.exe.

Platform independant would be to use

```
System.lineSeparator().getBytes()
```